# Connect to Google Analytics from Google App Engine without authenticating every 60 mins

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics-api

I have a unique constraint to connect to google analytics from app engine - retrieve the data do the calculations and change the data in website.

Everything has to be done automatically and no manual interactions. But there is a problem with google authentication.

I followed various tutorials to connect to GA from app engine but it seems authentication is the big problem.

eg: Followed the below tutorial and when i run the code in my local , it will open browser to authenticate and able to successfully retrieve the result. 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

Also, followed one of the good link http://www.marinamele.com/use-google-analytics-api-with-python but it seems authentication problem when we run in cloud.

Also tried storing credentials in client_secrets.json file and deployed to app engine and it was working for 60 mins, after that access_token expired and not able to reach analytics api and 500 error was thrown.

Any suggestions on how to connect to google analytics from google app engine via a crob job to get the analytics data, do the computation and change the database to show different content in website.

Comment: Why don't you just refresh the Access Token using Refresh Token after expiration ?

Comment: how to do that ?? and we cannot save the token back to file in google app engine. Currently i am having credentials.dat file but you will not be able to write to the file again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [offline access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline)

First of all you need to generate the necesaries tokens (access token and refresh token): follow the [step by step](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#obtainingaccesstokens) or see [complete example](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#example)

After obtaining the tokens you should have a json similar to this one:

```
{ 
    "access_token" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
    "token_type" : "Bearer", 
    "expires_in" : 3600, 
    "refresh_token" : "X/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
}
```

(*With some values instead of `X's`*)

You should use this `json` to do the authentication. Internally if the `access token` is expired the authentication will use the `refresh token` to generate a new one.

This whole protocol is called Auth 2.0, if you are interested in reading more about it, [check here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth)